# Oozie Reduce Join does not work

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I installed OOZIE and can run it, but I have got another problem with OOZIE and my project:
 The Java code works properly, but when I try to implement this in Oozie then it does not work any more. Something is wrong with my map Phase output specification in Oozie but I do not know what.

My jar file (name wordcount1.jar) consists of:
--JoinMapper$MovieMapper
--JoinMapper$FigureMapper
--JoinReducer

Here is my error log:
2016-03-09 01:24:30,441  INFO CallbackServlet:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W@wordcount1] callback for action [0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W@wordcount1]
2016-03-09 01:24:30,812  INFO MapReduceActionExecutor:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-workflow] JOB[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W@wordcount1] action completed, external ID [job_201603082221_0037]
2016-03-09 01:24:30,912  WARN MapReduceActionExecutor:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-workflow] JOB[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W@wordcount1] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain], main() threw exception, null
2016-03-09 01:24:31,120  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-workflow] JOB[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W@wordcount1] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2016-03-09 01:24:31,250  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-workflow] JOB[0000017-160308222246102-oozie-oozi-W] ..

I have got the following job.properties file:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=joinoozie
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/training/${examplesRoot}
inputDir1=movies1
inputDir2=figures1
```

My workflow.xml file is as follows:
    `<workflow-app name="example-workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="wordcount1" />
    <!-- WordCount MapReduce job -->
    <action name="wordcount1">
        <map-reduce>
               <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
               <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
             <prepare>

             </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>                                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingInputFormat</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>             <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                     <name>mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats</name>          <value>${inputDir1};org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat,${inputDir2};org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                     <name>mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.mappers</name>              <value>${inputDir1};JoinMapper$MovieMapper,${inputDir2};JoinMapper$FigureMapper</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
                    <value>JoinReducer</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                   <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                   <value>output_oozie</value>
                </property>
           </configuration>
    </map-reduce>

    <ok to="end" />
        <error to='end'/>
    </action>
<end name="end" />
</workflow-app>`

Could somebody please help me with this issue? Would be great..
Thanks,
Andi

Comment: I found a hint that "The actionConf needs to be copied over with WF Job default configs." - Does anybody know where the actionConf needs to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

Oozie provides a default set of properties corresponding to different action types in the workflow. You can read more about the locations and the order in which the properties are set [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/AG_ActionConfiguration.html)

Comment: if the answer helped, can you upvote and mark it as an answer? It might help others who run into a similar problem.